# Android wear custom layout notifications

Tags: android, layout, notifications, wear-os

I'm playing with Android Wear notifications a little and use the DataApi to trigger them from the wear device.
Nevertheless, I don't manage to figure out how we could have notifications like the demo cards in the android Wear mobile application.

For example : *public transport* or *flight info* or even the *weather forecast* cards.

I tried a *setDisplayIntent* but it is only showing when the user swipe the notif up.

**As it is written in the doc**

> Note: When the notification is peeking on the homescreen, the system
>   displays it with a standard template that it generates from the
>   notification's semantic data. This template works well on all
>   watchfaces. When users swipe the notification up, they'll then see the
>   custom activity for the notification.

What I am looking for is a way to **change this default template**, as Google do in the demo cards.

Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Have all a very good day and thanks for your help.

jn.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible in current version of API.

Comment: aargh. But if Google is able to do it, does that mean that it is available but APIs are not documented?
Moreover, what do you think of the idea to use a "Notification.Builder" setContent(RemoteViews views)
>>>Supply a custom RemoteViews to use instead of the platformtemplate.

and trigger it from the wear device?

Comment: The collapsed form of the weather forecast, package shipping, and others look like the default template - can you show an example of a custom template peeking on the homescreen?

Comment: It is currently possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603086/custom-ui-for-android-wear-notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Wayne Piekarski, it is not possible for now to get the exact same look of the collapsed sample cards: https://plus.google.com/u/0/100517480770286602327/posts/2o4SVBhWg5z

However, you can use `Spannable` to change the font weight or the text color.

```
String title = "My notification title!";
    Spannable customTitle = new SpannableString(title);
    customTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xff83ae7b), 0, title.length(), 0);

    Notification notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    ...
                    .setContentTitle(customTitle)               
                    ...
            .build();
```

Comment: I missed that discussion on Google+. **Thank you Nicolas** for showing it to me.
It is clearly the beginning of the answer, I hope Google will release more APIs soon!