# Custom UI for Android Wear Notifications

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

Hii I want to create Custom UI for android wear notification, and not AW app.
Please suggest if there are any libraries or anything available for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not available yet, most likely it will be in the future.

EDIT: Future is now. You can do this by passing own custom `Activity` by `setDisplayIntent()`, code sample:

```
public Notification buildNotification(Context context) {
            Intent displayIntent = new Intent(context, AnimatedNotificationDisplayActivity.class);
            displayIntent.putExtra(BasicNotificationDisplayActivity.EXTRA_TITLE, context.getString(nameResId));
            PendingIntent displayPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, displayIntent, 0);
            return buildBasicNotification(context)
.extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
.setDisplayIntent(displayPendingIntent))
.build();
}
```

Comment: I just wrote it is not available. How do you expect code sample for something not possible?